# How to run multi pipeline in logstash using The Elastic stack (ELK) powered by Docker and Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, logstash, elastic-stack

I am using  [this_repo](https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk) to get started running ELK with Docker.

my question is regarding the logstash image in the docker-compose file:

When I run locally I have 3 files

```
#general settings
logstash.yml
#pipeline setting
pipeline.yml
#a pipe line configuration
myconf.conf1
```

when I want to use multi pipeline I use the pipeline.yml file to control all the different pipeline I am running

```
# Example of my pipeline.yml
- pipeline.id: my-first-pipeline
  path.config: "/etc/logstash/my-first-pipeline.config"
  pipeline.workers: 2
- pipeline.id: super-swell-pipeline
  path.config: "/etc/logstash/super-swell-pipeline.config"
  queue.type: persisted
```

In the repo I am using as guideline I can only find logstash.yml
and I am not understanding how to can I add pipelines.
the only running pipeline is the default "main" which by default only run logstash.conf
I tried different configurations, all field

How can I add pipeline.yml to the docker?
or what is the best practice running multi pipelines with this docker-compose file?

appreciate any help

docker-compose/logstash form the repo:

```
  logstash:
    build:
      context: logstash/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./logstash/config/logstash.yml
        target: /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
        read_only: true
      - type: bind
        #can be either a host path or volume name.
        source: ./logstash/pipeline
        #is the container path where the volume is mounted
        target: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
        read_only: true
    ports:
      - "5000:5000/tcp"
      - "5000:5000/udp"
      - "9600:9600"
    environment:
      LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
```

DockerFILE:

```
ARG ELK_VERSION

# https://www.docker.elastic.co/
FROM docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:${ELK_VERSION}

# Add your logstash plugins setup here
# Example: RUN logstash-plugin install logstash-filter-json
```

logstash.yml

```
## Default Logstash configuration from Logstash base image.
## https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/master/docker/data/logstash/config/logstash-full.yml
#
http.host: "0.0.0.0"
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.hosts: [ "http://elasticsearch:9200" ]

## X-Pack security credentials
#
xpack.monitoring.enabled: false
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.username: elastic
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.password: changeme
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to mount your pipelines.yml file to the container as well. The default location Logstash is looking for a possible pipelines.yml file is `/usr/share/logstash/config/` (the same folder you've already mounted the logstash.yml file to).

Please note that you also have to update your current, local pipelines.yml file to the correct paths of the pipelines **inside the container**. To be precise, you need to change

`path.config: "/etc/logstash/my-first-pipeline.config"`

to

`path.config: "/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/my-first-pipeline.config"`

Also, have a look at these official guides for running Logstash with Docker and how to configure multiple pipelines:

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/docker-config.html#docker-config
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/multiple-pipelines.html

I hope I could help you!

**EDIT:**

The official documentations call the file pipeline**s**.yml instead of pipeline.yml